# CSS and Js not loading with https

Tags: 7, security

I'm trying to put my entire website under https connexion, but my css and js are not loaded. I don't know why.

I had this code to the htaccess at the root of the website :

```
  # Force HTTPS and WWW
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

And didn't touch anything else. If it's relevant, I'm using a hosting from online.net (french provider).

Comment: Refer this link,it may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452519/problems-loading-style-sheets-over-https

Comment: Thanks, you're probably right, but still have to figure where are the stylesheet links. Using zen theme.

Answer (score 1):

So after researches, everything work now and here is my configuration :

I putted this code into my sites/default/setting.php file :

```
$conf['https'] = FALSE;
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on') {
  $base_url = 'https://www.efficient-network.eu';
}
else {
  $base_url = 'http://www.efficient-network.eu';
}
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'On';
```

And needed to add a custom module to load every line in `<head> </head>` with https :

```
function https_process_html(&$vars)
{
    foreach (array('head', 'styles', 'scripts') as $replace) {
        if (!isset($vars[$replace])) {
            continue;
        }

        $vars[$replace] = preg_replace('/(src|href|@import )(url\(|=)(")http(s?):/', '$1$2$3', $vars[$replace]);
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's the proper method, but it works.